# Why generating json data from a list (array of arrays) results in a quotation mark problem?

Tags: json, pandas, list, dataframe

Considering the `dataframe` below:

```
  timestamp    coordinates
0 [402, 404]   [[2.5719,49.0044], [2.5669,49.0043]]
1 [345, 945]   [[2.5719,49.0044], [2.5669,49.0043]]
```

I'd like to generate a `json` file like below:

```
[
  {
    "vendor": 1,
    "path": [
             [2.5719,49.0044],
             [2.5669,49.0043]
            ],
    "timestamps": [402, 404]
  },
  {
    "vendor": 1,
    "path": [
             [2.5719,49.0044],
             [2.5669,49.0043]
            ],
    "timestamps": [345, 945]
  }]
```

To do so, my idea is:

1. For each row of my `df`, generate a new column `geometry`
   containing *row* `json` data
2. Then append all `geometries` in a `json`

However, my function below doesn't work.

```
df["geometry"] = df.apply(lambda row: {
    "vendor": 1,
    "path": row["coordinates"],
    "timestamps": row["timestamp"]
    },
    axis = 1)
```

Indeed, the result is (for example):
**Note the quote marks (`'`) around arrays in `path`**

```
{
 'vendor': 1,
 'path': ['[2.5719,49.0044]', '[2.5669,49.0043]'],
 'timestamps': [402, 404]
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the values in `coordinates` column are of type string. You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it to list:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["geometry"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: {
        "vendor": 1,
        "path": literal_eval(row["coordinates"]),
        "timestamps": row["timestamp"],
    },
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    timestamp                           coordinates                                                                                 geometry
0  [402, 404]  [[2.5719,49.0044], [2.5669,49.0043]]  {'vendor': 1, 'path': [[2.5719, 49.0044], [2.5669, 49.0043]], 'timestamps': [402, 404]}
1  [345, 945]  [[2.5719,49.0044], [2.5669,49.0043]]  {'vendor': 1, 'path': [[2.5719, 49.0044], [2.5669, 49.0043]], 'timestamps': [345, 945]}
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.  
`Coordinates` was a string!